# In which situation we use jmp_buf in C programming

Tags: c++

`jmp_buf` is used in which situation durinf C Programming.

`jmp_buf` is what? 
 I mean is it Keyword/data type ??

Comment: It's beneficial to lear *what* is `jmp_buf` *before* you ask how to use it.

Comment: Why not use Google? It is faster for this sort of question. 10 secs got http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/csetjmp/jmp_buf/

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/csetjmp/jmp_buf/

Comment: `jmp_buf` is a standard C function; if you know C, you know `jmp_buf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jmp_buf` is a type to hold information to restore calling environment
This is an array type capable of storing the information of a calling environment to be restored later. [Refer this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/csetjmp/jmp_buf/)

This information is filled by calling macro `setjmp` and can be restored by calling function `longjmp`.

An example of the same is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11879227/1064610) .